# PHP on Centos cant connect to Firebird on Centos remote server

Tags: php, apache, centos, firebird

I have a problem to connect using PHP 7.0 and Interbase to a remote Firebird server.

Server: Debian 6, Firebird 2.5.
Client: Centos 7, Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/7.0.27

Interbase Extension
Firebird/InterBase Support  dynamic
Compile-time Client Library Version Firebird API version 25
Run-time Client Library Version LI-V6.3.7.27050 Firebird 2.5

Error:

"Unable to complete network request to host "192.168.1.11". Failed to establish a connection."

```
$hostFirebird = "192.168.1.11:/usr/data/pcondominio.fdb";
$userFirebird = "sysdba";
$passFirebird = "masterkey";

$connFirebird = ibase_connect( $hostFirebird, $userFirebird, $passFirebird, 'ISO8859_1', '100', '1' ) or die(  ibase_errmsg() );
```

Using ISQL-FB, I can connect normal in the same machine of Apache.

[image: Normal connection]

I just installed the tcpdump and run the command: `tcpdump -i ens192 dst 192.168.1.11` and nothing appears when I run the PHO script, just the error on php: Unable to complete network request to host "192.168.1.11". Failed to establish a connection.

Running any command or connection in ISQL show: listening on ens192, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes 03:04:55.513299 IP 192.168.1.9.36274 > 192.168.1.11.gds_db: Flags [P.], seq 579467323:579467335, ack 779311378, win 691, options [nop,nop,TS val 19068358 ecr 197113773], length 12

Looks like the Apache/PHP don't even try to connect.

I have no clue about what's happening.

Comment: Which version of firebird? Architecture?

Comment: Please do not post images, post text. And is this host you used isql-fb, the same as the one with Apache?

Comment: Server: 192.168.1.11 (Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.6, Firebird 2.5.0)

Comment: Yes, the host of isql-fb is the same with Apache.

Comment: may there be some antivirus or firewall (ipchains, netfilter, etc) blocking Apache's connection attempts? May u see some TCP sniffer like WireShark to see how connection is being attempted by isql and by Apache ?

Comment: I just installed the tcpdump and run the command: tcpdump -i ens192 dst 192.168.1.11 src 192.168.1.11 and nothing apears when i run the php scrip, just the error on php: Unable to complete network request to host "192.168.1.11". Failed to establish a connection.
In ISQL show: listening on ens192, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
03:04:55.513299 IP 192.168.1.9.36274 > 192.168.1.11.gds_db: Flags [P.], seq 579467323:579467335, ack 779311378, win 691, options [nop,nop,TS val 19068358 ecr 197113773], length 12

Comment: Looks like the Apache/Php don't even try to connect.

Comment: You ignore my question about an architecture: classic or super?

Comment: @rstrelba Firebird Superserver

Comment: does the same tcpdump show traffic when u connect via iSQL tool?

Comment: @Arioch'The See the paragraph starting with _"Running any command or connection in ISQL show: [..]"_

Comment: Try isql-fb not under root

Comment: @rstrelba, Its working too...

Comment: look to parameter RemoteBindAddress in firebird.conf

Comment: @rstrelba this parameter is commented: #RemoteBindAddress =

Comment: Try  RemoteBindAddress = localhost and restart server

Comment: @rstrelba Still no working

Comment: Update, when i run the php script direct by command line they works. I need to give more permissions to user apache?

Comment: Solved, in linux i run this command: 'setenforce 0' and now its working.